# Make sure that bean action method is invoked after file upload listener is finished

Tags: multithreading, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

When an user uploads a file with the Primefaces fileUpload Element the server method are only invoked after the file is uploaded. Then I have the problem when a form is submitted and the file is not fully transferred to the server I don't know how long I should wait in the submit method.

To wait during the submit method I created a Thread which will live as long as the upload takes, but as pointed before the method "handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event)" is not triggered when the user selects a file.

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        System.out.println("start fileupload");
        FileUploadWaiter fileUploadWaiter = new FileUploadWaiter();
        fileUploadThread = new Thread(fileUploadWaiter);
        fileUploadThread.start();
        System.out.println("fileupload triggered");
        fileType = event.getFile().getContentType();
        file = convertUploadedFileToByte(event.getFile());
        fileUploadWaiter.stop();
        try {
            fileUploadThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //
        }
        System.out.println("upload fertig");// TODO
    }
```

On the page:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
...
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{eintrag.handleFileUpload}"
                                    mode="advanced" update="msgFileUpload" auto="true"
                                    sizeLimit="#{config.fileUploadMaxSize}"
                                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpeg|jpg|png)$/" label="Auswählen"
                                    disable="false" id="fileUpload" />
...
</h:form>
```

The Code:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        System.out.println("start fileupload");
        FileUploadWaiter fileUploadWaiter = new FileUploadWaiter();
        fileUploadThread = new Thread(fileUploadWaiter);
        fileUploadThread.start();
        System.out.println("fileupload triggered");
        fileType = event.getFile().getContentType();
        file = convertUploadedFileToByte(event.getFile());
        fileUploadWaiter.stop();
        try {
            fileUploadThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //
        }
        System.out.println("fileupload finished");// TODO
    }
```

I found no hints in the Primefaces manual

Comment: Why not block the rest of the page/disable components while the file upload completes?

Comment: Whatever you try, never, *never*, **never** manually create a `Thread` in a Java EE application.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to kolossus, I blocked the submit button during file upload

page.xhtml:

```
<script>
    function disableButtons() {
        $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:fileUpload_input')).prop('disabled', true);
        $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:erstellen')).prop('disabled', true);
    }

    function enableButtons() {
        if (!PF('upload').files.length) {
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:fileUpload_input')).prop('disabled', false);
                $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:erstellen')).prop('disabled', false);
                }
    }
</script>


<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{eintrag.handleFileUpload}"
    mode="advanced" update="msgFileUpload" auto="true"
    sizeLimit="#{config.fileUploadMaxSize}"
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpeg|jpg|png)$/" label="Auswählen"
    id="fileUpload" dragDropSupport="false"
    invalidSizeMessage="Dateigröße überschritten #{config.fileUploadMaxSize}"
    onstart="disableButtons();"
    oncomplete="enableButtons();"
    widgetVar="upload" />
```